# With .Cells(Rows.Count, 3), what does the 3 represent?

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't been able to find an answer to what a single number represents here. I'm trying to find the row where the last occurrence of a string occurs, copy that entire row, and insert it below that row. To try and get the first part, where I can find the row value of the last occurrence, what does this "3" represent?

```
Dim shortname As String
Dim endRow As Integer
Dim lastRowSearchValue As Range

shortname = "CATS"

With ActiveSheet
endRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 33).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To endRow
        If .Cells(i, 33) = shortname Then
            lastRowSearchValue = i
        End If
    Next i
End With

lastRowSearchValue.Copy
```

Comment: 33 is the column number, or Column AG. Your code searches for CATS in column AG starting from row 1 to the last row with data and when found it assigns the found row number to lastRowSearchValue which is incorrect because lastRowSearchValue is a range. Correct would be Set lastRowSearchValue = .Cells(i, 33) to be able to continue with lastRowSearchValue.Copy

Answer (score 0):

`Cells(Row,Column)`

So it is the Column number.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells

So `.Cells(Rows.Count, 33).End(xlUp).Row` is starting at the bottom of Column 33 and and searching up till it finds the first cell from the bottom that has a value.

Then the loop is looping from the first Row to that last row and checking the value in that column on each row.

If `.Cells(i, 33) = shortname` Then is then checking that cell, each one in that column if its value is the same as `shortname`

but this is probably an x/y problem as `lastRowSearchValue = i` does not return a range but a long:

You want:

```
Set lastRowSearchValue = .Cells(i,33)
```

Comment: so that's telling the code to search through all rows, from the end of the file up to the beginning, and look specifically for "shortname" in column 33?

Answer (score 0):

## Correcting Code

`endRow` has to be declared as long because `.Rows.Count` exceeds the limit for `Integer`.
33 is the column number, or Column `AG`. Your code searches for CATS in column `AG` starting from row 1 to the last row with data and when found it assigns the found row number to `lastRowSearchValue` which is incorrect because `lastRowSearchValue` is a range. Correct would be `Set lastRowSearchValue = .Cells(i, 33)` to be able to continue with `lastRowSearchValue.Copy`. It will continue searching until the end to find other occurrences of CATS. To stop this you can add the line `Exit For` to exit the loop when CATS was found. But since you do want to find the last occurrence, you don't wanna do that.

I've chosen to declare lastRow as Long to get the last occurring row and then copy that row one row below. To make it less confusing, I have used the column letters.

### The Code

```
Sub CopyRowBelowWhenFound()

    Dim shortname As String
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    shortname = "CATS"

    With ActiveSheet
        endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To endRow
            If .Cells(i, "AG") = shortname Then
                lastRow = i
            End If
        Next i
        With .Cells(lastRow, "AG")
            .EntireRow.Copy .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need cell rather row number. Anyway, the following code tries to find this cell:

```
Sub FFF()
    Dim cell As Range, lastRowSearchValue&
    Set cell = Columns(33).Find(What:="CATS", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        lastRowSearchValue = cell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "No value found", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: lastRowSearchValue&? LookIn is the third argument that is saved each time, although this will only fail if you have previously searched comments.